# Pentaho biserver-ce 5: RepositorySynchronizer plugin issue

Tags: tomcat, jcr, pentaho-cde

I have installed the Pentaho BI-Server CE 5. I have also created new dashboard in it using MDX query. As with CE 5 all the data is stored into JCR and not on file system (as it was with 4.5 etc.). So I try installing the plugin RepositorySynchronizer from marketplace. After installation I restart tomcat (pentaho server) and tried to open RepositorySynchronizer plugin, but it gives error like "**Check the paths of JCR and File System in prs.xml**" which i solved using this: http://redmine.webdetails.org/issues/2961 discussion. So now my prs.xml looks like

location path="jcr-solution:file:///E:/Suraj/Pentaho/biserver-ce/tomcat/bin/" name="JCR"

location path="E:/Suraj/Pentaho/biserver-ce/pentaho-solutions/system/../repositorySynchronizer" name="File System"

As stated, with above settings I can Open the RepositorySynchronizer plugin, but it Shows 0 number of files in all (JCR+filesystem category)

I don't know what exactly is went wrong or I did any wrong configuration!

Any help on this issue is much appreciated.

Thanks In advance.
Suraj.

(p.s.: My ultimate goal is to bring my work(dashboards) to my local file system)

Answer (score 0):

You should edit prs.xml as below

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
  <prs>
    <locations>
            <!--<location path="jcr-solution:/pentaho!/" name="JCR"/>-->
            <location path="jcr-solution:/pentaho/" name="JCR"/>
            <location path="${cpk.solution.system.dir}/../repositorySynchronizer" name="File System"/>
    </locations>
    <excludes>
            <!-- Exclude all dot folders and files -->
            <exclude pattern=".*/\.[^/]*(/.*)?"/>
            <!-- Exclude sample folders -->
            <exclude pattern=".*/bi-developers(/.*)?"/>
            <exclude pattern=".*/cde(/.*)?"/>
            <exclude pattern=".*/plugin-samples(/.*)?"/>
            <exclude pattern=".*/Steel\sWheels(/.*)?"/>
    </excludes>
    <last_synch>1400121112610</last_synch>
</prs>
```

comment or delete this path="jcr-solution:/pentaho!/" and add path="jcr-solution:/pentaho/"